# cname to subfolder re-write with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

what I want to do is redirect:

images.example.com/filename

to

example.com/images/filename

I tried:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^(images)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To no avail. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why are you serving requests for google.com?

Comment: I used google for example purposes

Comment: OK, it may be worth reading [RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt). It specifies domains that are reserved precisely for example/documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {%HTTP_HOST} ^images.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note: when trying it out, you might want to remove the =301 because browsers will  cache those redirects since they are "permanent" which can make it hard to test changes you make because it might appear they aren't taking effect but they really are.

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll I hope you were able to get your issue resolved.  If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted so I can get credit for it.  Thanks